# submiting form doesn't work with jquery

Tags: jquery, validation

hi i have a simple form with some fields that i should validate its a simple html code , i am using a jquery code to validate my form

```
if(valider(price) && allowvide(sg) && 
   allowvide(sh) && allowvide(nbc) && 
   allowvide(nbs) && allowvide(etage) && check){ 
    alert('ok');
    form.submit();
}else{
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
    form.submit(false);
}
```

the function valider and allowvide return true when its correct and false if its not , the function are working , when i put everything correct my form is submitted , but when i do some errors i get notification about errors but when i correct the fields i can't submit the form , i am wondering is it the problem that i do a `form.submit(false)` and after that i do `form.submit()` i 've tried `form.submit(true)` but nothing. what could i do

Comment: This `form.submit(false);` should be this `return false;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
<form onsubmit="return checkform()"..
```

js

```
function checkform(){
   //.. all your variables come here.. 
   if(valider(price) && allowvide(sg) && 
      allowvide(sh) && allowvide(nbc) && 
      allowvide(nbs) && allowvide(etage) && check){ 
      alert('ok');
      return true;//submits the form
   }else{
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
      return false;//doesnot submit the form
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this :-

```
$('form').submit(function(){
if($(this).valid()) return true;
return false;
});
```